# GCP - Log Metrics - Regex for labels to Convert UTC Time into EST Time

Tags: regex, logging, google-cloud-platform, label

Not sure if anyone has experienced this issue before - but i am trying to convert UTC Time

```
2022-02-11T02:10:22.741394075Z
```

To EST Time - within Google Log Metrics at the time of Label defining. If anyone of you have been able to achieve this then please let me know would appreciate assistance on this and haven't come across any documentation to refer to.

Comment: Are you using Cloud Console or the command-line (`gcloud`)?

Comment: Do you mean log filtering or are you creating a log metric?

Comment: And what do you mean by "at the time of Label defining"?

Comment: Hi @DazWilkin, Thanks for your prompt response! It's at the time of creating Log Metrics - we get the option of adding labels. That's when i am trying to apply Regex to convert 2022-02-11T02:10:22.741394075Z time to regular EST time.

Comment: It's been some time since I used log metrics and it's unclear why you would include any time-series in the filter that defines a metric. The metric should be time-independent as it results in a Monitoring time-series (that you could then filter by time).

Comment: Intuitively, it seems a poor approach (but sincerely I'm not that familiar so you could be doing something entirely reasonable) because localized time is mostly a consumer/end-user/presentation benefit. Although logging presents UTC strings, it's actually surprising that it doesn't use e.g. UNIX epoch. The system needs a consistent measurement system that 2 logs can be determined to be before|after|same time as one another. When I (e.g. living in EST) want to observe the metric or logs, I can ask the system to render the results using my local timezone.

Comment: Asking another way: Why do you need the system to translate every (!) log entry from UTC to ETC before processing? When it would be easy to ask it to do this after processing on a much smaller dataset?

Comment: That's because we are using Grafana as a Visualization tool - which gives us limited to no ability to convert UTC time to EST :/ , If you believe there's could be a better approach i am all ears.

Comment: Let's see what others more familiar with Grafana plus Cloud Monitoring (Log) Metrics have to say. Grafana must be using UTC (or UNIX epoch) internally otherwise, it would be very difficult to correlate disparate time-series sources. Usually, machines use a universal time basis e.g. UTC and then the human says "make everything ETC" and that's done as a final, output step. But, I don't know your configuration and defer to your understanding of it.

Comment: Everything you said is correct, the only problem with Visualization tools is it comes with limited solution unless we decide to save data in their cluster in order to manipulate it(comes the cost part), well that's the only solution there is for now.

Comment: If the answer was useful, please mark the answer as upvoted for greater visibility for community members.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In GCP, There is no option to change the timezone by using a regular expression within Google Log Metrics at the time of Label defining.

Usually a regular expression (shortened as regex or regexp; also referred to as rational expression) is a sequence of characters that specifies a search pattern in text and such patterns are used by string-searching algorithms for "find" or "find and replace" operations on strings, or for input validation but not for changing.